# Add in the url attachment loop the wp_link_pages of the post

Tags: posts, attachments

Complete Code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>                                                                                 
<main id="news_posts"> 
  <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <!-- Post -->
  <section>
    <div class="post">
      <div class="area_news_post">
        <h1 class="post-title">             
          <?php the_title(); ?> 
        </h1>            
        <div class="news_data"> 
          <span>Date: 
          </span>
          <?php the_time( 'd/m/Y') ?> 
        </div>                         
      </div>       
      <div class="post-body">

       <div class="images-post">
<?php
        $attachments = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'   => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => 5,
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
               'order' => 'ASC',
        ) );
        if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                ?>
          <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' ); ?>
                  <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title ); ?>
<?php
$parent = wp_get_post_parent_id( $attachment->ID );?>
<a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink( $parent) ) ?><?php echo $page ?>/">
<?php the_title ?>
</a>
 <?php  } } ?>
    </div>

<?php the_content() ?>
</div>

<?php  wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . 'Page:' . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        <?php $post_anicast_idurl = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_my_url_anicast', true);
 if (!empty($post_anicast_idurl)) { ?>    
<iframe width="100%" height="120" src="<?php echo $post_anicast_idurl; ?>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<?php }?>  
        <div id="area_avatar_autor">             
          <div class="avatar">
            <?php if (function_exists ( 'mt_profile_img' ) ) { $author_id=$post->post_author; mt_profile_img( $author_id, array('size' => 'thumbnail', 'attr' => array( 'alt' => get_the_author(),'title' => get_the_author()   ),'echo' => true ));
}?>
          </div>
          <div class="author_post"> 
            <span>By: 
            </span>
            <?php the_author() ?> 
          </div>
          <div class="views_post">
            <span> Views: 
            </span>
            <?php if(!current_user_can('administrator')){ echo setPostViews(get_the_ID()); } ?>
<?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());?>
          </div>
          <div class="share_post_link">
            <span class="label share_bg">Share:
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="share_link" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo wp_get_shortlink(); ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="share_social_tags">
          <div class="social_share">
            <a href="#" title="Facebook"> Facebook
            </a>
            <a href="#" title="Twiiter"> Twiiter
            </a>
            <a href="#" title="Google+"> Google +
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="tags_post">
            <?php the_tags( ) ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post_edit"> 
          <?php edit_post_link('Editar','',''); ?>
        </div>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class="navigation">
          <div class="navigation-previous">
            <?php previous_post_link( '%link',' &laquo; Anterior') ?>
          </div>
          <div class="navigation-next">
            <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Próxima &raquo;') ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Navigation -->
        <div id="disqus_thread">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /Post -->
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php else : ?>
      <!-- Post -->
      <div class="post">
        <div class="post-top">
          <div class="post-bottom">
            <div class="post-title">
              <h2> Not found
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="post-entry">
              <p> Nothing found. Come Back
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="post-info">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /Post -->
      <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      </main>
    </div>
  <!-- /Main -->
  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm trying to add in the attachment loop url the wp_link_pages function but I did not succeed, my current url:

[image]

I've been trying for some time but I can not add wp_link_pages to the url attachment loop, I'd like it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Where are you executing `wp_link_pages()`?

Comment: Yes <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'themeone' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>

Comment: Can you update the code block above with it? My suspicion is you're running it outside The Loop.

Comment: Ok, so you're looking to get the permalink of the attachment's parent post to be in the wrapping <a> element?

Comment: Yes, I do not know how to do it

Comment: I edited my answer using `wp_get_post_parent_id()`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the parent post, you would use the `wp_get_post_parent_id()` function.

So in your `foreach` loop, you would want to add something like:

```
$parent = wp_get_post_parent_id( $attachment->ID );
<a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink( $parent ) ) ?>">
   // Rest of your HTML
</a>
```

Comment: Did not return the Attachment

Comment: Code update:  http://pastebin.com/QYrcGEgr  I want to insert the wp_link_pages function in the attachment url

Comment: Part of the problem is resolved.

I am dividing each image of the post with the page break function each image is on a page, I would like the parent post url to appear in the attachment loop using the wp_link_pages function that is in the post.
You can get the URL of the parent post and show the number of the post with the wp_link_pages function. Same as this image, I edited it in the browser to show how I want it to be.

Comment: `Example:  

Image Url 01:
http://localhost/wordpress/blog/post-teste/

Image Url 02:
http://localhost/wordpress/blog/post-teste/2`

Comment: I can't see those images in a comment

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/02011YE.png

Comment: so `anime` is the post slug?

Comment: No, anime is the name of the post

Comment: In that last image, I do not have a browser to show how I want a URL to be

Comment: Then what I posted should work. The `wp_get_post_parent_id()` function will take the current attachment, look up what that post's ID is, and store that post in an object/array called `$parent`. You can then use `the_permalink( $parent ) to get the parent post's URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55595/discussion-between-rikuo-nura-and-belinus).

Comment: I put it that way and it did not work. http://pastebin.com/hAcfpgyV

Comment: What was your output?

Comment: In the URL I returned this in all images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApEOd.png

Comment: I need to do it this way, example https://www.animeunited.com.br/blog/dicas-de-animes-com-protagonistas-overpowers-recomendacao/

Comment: I think I'm doing it wrong.
My logic: Create

1st Second Editor
2º Catch all the thumbnals of the post
3rd Add full image function
4th Add correct page function

In the first post, add a gallery, do not add the text that matches the added image, then place no links from the gallery and the second editor.   Would that be so?

Comment: If you want to do something like that image gallery, then your output is going to be dependent on the JavaScript library you use to drive it. Find one you like and then you'll have to get the proper HTML structure and then go from there.

Comment: I found this function, my code is almost ready, I just need to add the caption  http://pastebin.com/Ssf6eSVV   Can you help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: The caption is the `post_excerpt` property of the post object.